# Sliding divs based on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Been stumped all day trying to find a plugin to fit my needs or trying to build something myself. I've got the basics set up, I'm just trying to get a nice smooth transition, instead of the jarring jump to the anchor.

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div id="content-container">
    <div class="slide" id="home">

    </div>
    <div class="slide" id="about">

    </div>
    <div class="slide" id="musings">

    </div>
    <div class="slide" id="socials">

    </div>
    <div class="slide" id="contact">

    </div>
```

```
 /* CSS */
#content-container{
    height: 100%;
    width: 500%;
}
#home{   
    background: url(assets/slide1.gif) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: 0;
}
#about{   
    background: url(assets/slide2.gif) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: 1;
}
#musings{   
    background: url(assets/slide3.gif) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: 2;
}
#socials{   
    background: url(assets/slide4.gif) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: 3;
}
#contact{   
    background: url(assets/slide5.gif) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: 4;
}
.slide{
    height: 100%;
    width: 20%;
}
```

All I'm trying to get to work is a basic set of buttons to control which one will slide in from the right. If I can get them to slide left/right based on which one I'm looking at/which one I'm moving too, that would be a bonus too. Had no luck for the past few hours non stop research.

Comment: If you want better answers I recommend setting up a JSFiddle

Comment: Dude, No body have an enough to time to go though your code Kindly be precise !

Comment: @user3011961 Learn to scan read. Quite simply, all that question states is: _I want a JQuery plugin that does X, Y and Z_. Simples! *chirp*

Comment: @JamieBarker Thanks for that, didn't want to give it the time of day. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [JQuery Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle)? In particular, [this page](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/int2.html)